# Run Java packages on unsupported Java Version

Tags: java, macos

I have a PowerMac and it is giving me bad version number on some .jars. I would love to make it seem like I am running Java 6. How would I spoof the version? Let me also say I am running **PowerPC and Leopard**

Comment: You want to spoof the version returned when a program asks "what version am I running on"?  If so, I doubt there's a way, short of modifying the JDK somehow.

Comment: This is caused by an **incompatible class file version**; it is *not* just a matter of "Java reports wrong version". The only solution is to *upgrade* the JVM or *recompile* the classes for the lower version. (There might be a tool to alter the class file format into something compatible, but this seems iffy at best.)

Comment: I have OpenJDK 7 and Java 1.5

Comment: @Keaton Then use the Java 7 JVM - it sounds like it is using the Java 5 version (there is a way to specify this in the System Preferences ..?)

Comment: The problem is it doesnt work on that either. It absolutely hates it.

Comment: "It's giving me bad version number on some .jars" and "It absolutely hates it" are hopelessly vague.  Please cut/paste some actual error messages.

Comment: @paulsm4 1/13/13 7:44:33 PM [0x0-0x214214].com.apple.JarLauncher[4657] java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file

Comment: OK: Thank you.  "UnsupportedClassVersionError" is what you get when you try running a JDK 6 (or higher) .class with a JRE 5 (or lower) version of Java.  You goal is to get your Java 5 out of the picture.  Java prefs is usually the best way.  Installing a Java version that works with your Java prefs might be your best bet.  I'm not on a Mac, so I don't know what your options are.  Can you just use the [Oracle JDK](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jdk.html)?

Comment: @paulsm4 I can't, I have to use my SoyLatte. I can run some apps now, but I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.

Comment: PROBLEM: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0'.  WORKAROUND: type "`xhost +`" (allow unrestricted access): https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=296443

Comment: @paulsm4 said: xhost:  unable to open display ":0"

Comment: @paulsm4 I am using the X11 Window now and I get this on one jar:     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at mc.now.ui.Installer.main(Installer.java:559)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown OS: darwin
        at mc.now.util.InstallerConfig.<clinit>(InstallerConfig.java:56)                                                                   And this on another: #  Internal Error (os_bsd_zero.cpp:232), pid=720, tid=4028116992
#  Error: caught unhandled signal 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely problem is that you have Java 6 JAR files and you are trying to run them on an old Java installation.

> How would I spoof the version?

The answer to your question is that you can't.  The way to run Java 6 specific JAR files it to use a Java 6 (or later) JRE or JDK.

The problem is that the format of Java class files has changed, and your installation can't cope with the new format.  And this is not a gratuitous change that you can pretend doesn't exist.  Java 6 (actually Java 5) has support for generic types, enums, annotations and other things.  Assuming that the JARs contain code that uses these new language features, an older JRE simply won't know what to do with them.

There are two solutions:

- Upgrade your Java installations to the required level on all machines.  This is the best solution ... if it is an option ... because it means your users will get the benefit of security and bug fixes and performance enhancements.  (And progress of your project won't be held back by the constraint of supporting legacy platforms.)
- Compile all of your code for compatibility with the oldest version of Java that you still have to use.  Either compile on the corresponding old JDK, or on a more recent JDK using appropriate -source / -target / -Xbootclasspath options ... as described by the `javac` manual page.

The catch with the second solution is that if the source code for the JAR files in question uses recently added Java language features or APIs, then recompiling for the older platform will fail.  To fix this you will need to rewrite your code to replace the nice modern stuff with archaic stuff.  Not a good solution, IMO.

---

The other possibility is that you are seeing corrupted JAR files.  This is unlikely, but it can happen if you are using applets or webstart, and the server is delivering error pages instead of JAR files.

---

The third possibility is that you simply haven't configured your Mac's Java installation's correctly.  Making Java 7 the default *should* allow you to run everything without class version problems.  (Thanks @paulsm4)  Note that I can't help you with that ... 'cos I don't use Java on a Mac.

Comment: Also: Try setting "Java Preferences" so that everything (command-line JRE, JDK, Browser plugins, etc etc) all point to your OpenJDK7: http://www.java.net/forum/topic/jdk/java-se/java-preferences-using-jre-7u6-mac-os-x

Comment: Okay, I really installed SoyLatte, A BSD port for PowerPC. It has to be set via the bash_profile. The Java prefs only recognize JRE 1.5

Comment: Could I add it to the Java pref pane?

Comment: This might work: [SoyLatte bundle template](http://www.malcolmhardie.com/weblogs/angus/2010/10/30/679/)

Comment: @paulsm4 I would love to use that but I am on Leopard PPC